# Shared hosting requirements / Deployment workflow

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, web-deployment, bower

I am evaluating [*kunstmaan bundles*](http://bundles.kunstmaan.be/) which is a cms built with (or on top of) symfony.

The requirements are:

- Node.js
- SASS
- Bower
- Grunt
- UglifyJS
- UglifyCSS

My guestion: **Are these applications only required in the development environment? What are the requirements to the production environment?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these will be used for development only:

- SASS is a preprocessor used to compile CSS from SASS or SCSS files.
- Bower is a package manager to manage (install/update/delete) javascript packages.  At some point you need to include the javascript that bower has installed for you, but I'm guessing that the CMS will have taken care of that for you.
- Grunt gives you development tools
- UglifyJS and UglifyCSS will minify your JS and CSS files.
- And finally node.js - in this scenario, node (and its package manager npm) is being used just to install the other packages mentioned above.

Aside from some way of including the packages installed by bower (as mentioned above), you won't need any of these in production.

Comment: As one of the creators of the Kunstmaan Bundles I can confirm this. As long as you prepare everything locally and deploy the full contents of your web folder, you don't need any of them on the production servers. We actually use this approach for some of our projects/clients (well, actually executing them on the production server during deploys was hell - I wouldn't recommend doing that :p).

Comment: @wimvds I've never used Kunstmaan Bundles.  So does the OP have to do anything to include the bower packages or is that built into the cms?